# Как отобразить JS код в самом веб-приложении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind

Всем привет) Я создаю веб-приложение со всеми шаблонами компонентов, которые когда-либо сам создавал. Идея заключается в том, чтобы на сайте отображался компонент, а справа его код. Подскажите, как и с помощью чего отображают код на сайтах.

Примером может служить сайт Tailwind, там есть шаблоны компонентов, а так же можно посмотреть код того или иного шаблона.

Comment: highlight.js ?...

Comment: Очень вероятно, что это то, что мне нужно. Я правильно понимаю, что сам код отображается с помощью тэгов <pre><code> ? А выделение этого кода делается с помощью этой библиотеки ?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: Спасибо ) Помогли )

Answer (score 0):

```
let displayJs = document.getElementById("displayJs").innerHTML =
`displayJs.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
    alert("")
});`
```